# How to copy a "prototype" view loaded from a nib file

Tags: macos, cocoa

I am developing an OS X cocoa control that looks like a table view on iOS. It allows the user to design its prototype cell (an `NSView`) in Xcode interface builder. My code needs to make multiple copies of the prototype cell. How do I do that? `[aView copy]` doesn't work. The nib file has other stuff other than the prototype cell, so I cannot just load the nib multiple times.

Comment: Why don't you divide the nib into the view content and the "other stuff"?

Comment: For convenience. Like in iOS development, you usually doesn't put your prototype cell in a separate nib.

Comment: I cannot see the advantage for convenience. Usually you put multi-instantiated parts in a separate nib.

Comment: In addition to convenience, what if you want to use the prototype nib in more than one nib of different classes? It'd be really handy (esp. with autolayout) to be able to do this.